# How I can send bug report if Lubuntu doesn't start?

Tags: bug-reporting

I found a `bug`

> When disk is full - Lubuntu 13.10 can't load.

I went to [Ubuntu page on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs) to search this "bug" but didn't find this "bug". I push button "Report a bug", but I see [this help wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), not the interface of "bug" submitting. Maybe I need to do something to get access of posting "bug reports"?

Comment: It sends you there so that you can create a bug report properly - the information to do so is in the wiki page. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Reporting_a_Bug It's not a bug however - if the drive is full then you need to deal with that.

Comment: But if the drive is full I can't remove anything if my computer can't boot. Your link - `Reporting an application crash` - it is not this situation - if I can't boot my system I can't do anything.

Comment: I fix this problem - I loaded from LiveUSB with Lubuntu and deleted one folder of 50 mb - after this I can normally start my PC, but I need post this issue like a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses Launchpad to keep track of bugs and their fixes. This page will guide you through the steps required to file a good and detailed report.

Read this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) on how to report a bug, and test if that is really a bug.

Comment: This page describe how to send bug report from running system, but how I can send bug report from system that can't boot?

Comment: You should have mentioned it in your question.

Comment: And also if a system does not boot how do you expect it to connect to internet and send report? Is that even possible just think.

Comment: I thought that I can just write this bug from another PC.